# Use function to display database value

Tags: jquery, ajax, asynchronous

I'm building an website that entirely consist of JavaScript (for fun).
I'm now adding the option to select a language which would change some parts of the website to that language (most hard coded words and sentences).

I'm now trying to do this by passing a value to a function that then does an ajax call and retrieves the word/sentences based on that value and the language set.

But because ajax is async it will not work. I found a great example only that kind of does what I want, but there is one problem.

Here is the fiddle code: http://jsfiddle.net/6xhxT/5/

```
$('#test').text(realData);
```

When I use this line (it's blocked in the example) it works great, but the problem is that I do not know the id of the div I'm putting the data in.

I use it like this

```
<div class="whatever">getWord(1)</div>
```

So the example works but I need to now the id of the div I put it in, but I do not want that. I want it to be put in the same place as where I call the function.

I do know I could use async: false, but I don't want to use that.

If what I want is not possible, then what should I use, I can use an array or sessionStorage, but is that wise considering the fact that there are probably thousands of words/sentences that it needs to load.

Comment: What does asynchronicity have to do with it?

Comment: Everything? because when I call the function it doesn't return a value (because it's async) But if I set async to false it will work, but I have to wait for the call to finish (and I don't want that).
So i want to make a async call and stil be able to display the result

Answer (score 0):

I can't really grasp what your approach is, but seems to me you could just loop through elements that should be translated and use `$( this )` to refer to the element.

```
$( '.i18n' ).each( function() {
    var $this = $( this );
    $this.load( 'url/to/translator', { text: $this.text() } );
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/eNK9w/

Comment: The problem is that I want this function to work for everything on my site, I also use it for thing like an image title or alt. So I would prefer to do just this
    <img src="" title="' + getWord(1) + '" alt="' + getWord(2) + '" />

Comment: `$( '<img src="foo.jpg">' ).appendTo( '#whatever' ).attr( 'title', getWord(1) ).attr( 'alt', getWord(2) )`